# TFS2010 BuildAgent using the .NET MSBuild instead of VS MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

How can I configure the BuildAgent to build my projects using the new MSBuild, that has shipped with VisualStudio 2013, instead of the .NET framework MSBuild.
This is what the current build agent uses:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
I would like that it uses this path:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe"

I already changed the ToolPath in the template, but it still tries to use the .NET framework msbuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to run the "new" msbuild.
It was enougth to change the ToolPath, but there is more, than one place, where the tool path property should be changed.

What I did:
I looked up for the workflow template, which my build was using (in my case it was the DefaultTemplate.xaml).
I looked for all occurences of the "Run MSBuild for Project" activities and in properties of this activity I have edited the "ToolPath" to use this path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64\" (including quotas). After changing two occurencies of this activity and checkin the changes it started working.

Comment: Changing the "ToolVersion" property to "12.0" worked for me; no need to hard code the path.